Mouse wheel rotary encoder
I've been designing a computer mouse to replace the now discontinued logitech g600, and am using an RP2040 module as the MCU. Everything on my journey has had design references available except for the scroll wheel (never thought the mouse sensor would have plenty of documentation and examples available)!
I bought some kailh scroll wheel encoders and I'm just so confused on how to wire/program it as I can't find any designs to reference on github/etc. And the documentation provided by kailh (also checked Alps brand data sheets) is still confusing me.
Can any one lend some advice on how to integrate it with an RP2040 module? Pointing me to any information or direction would be great!
Edit:
Here is the page for the encoder: https://www.kailhswitch.com/info/the-inruduction-of-mouse-wheel-rotary-encoder-33169856.html
Documentation on this is severely lacking but I thought I would be ok using a 'generic' since its only a 3 pin device, I bought them off of aliExpress.
Based on other research I believe I can connect 2 pins to any GPIO pins on the RP2040 and 'com' is ground. but I also have seen some circuits with capacitors etc which is why I was hoping for some advice.

Please [edit] and add the datasheet link for the encoder. (Not in the comments.)

There is just two pieces of information missng. What kind of interface the encoder has, and what kind of interfaces a RP2040 has available that it can be connected to. Many microcontrollers have timer/counter modules built-in that can be directly be connected to common rotary encoders for keeping count - but does the RP2040 have those?

@Justme: The RP2040 has a programmable digital interface peripheral.  Fun for hardware-assisted interfaces to WS2812 LEDs, one-wire busses..... or rotary encoders.  (It may also be possible to do quadrature decoding with the configurable-but-not-programmable peripherals)
